# browser.windows.create in Microsoft Edge opens window only in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm creating an extension for Microsoft Edge, and when I try to open new window with:

```
        browser.windows.create({url:"preview.html",left:50,top:100,type:"popup",width:800,height:1000});
```

it opens in fullscreen, and not with dimensions I called browser.windows.create method with.

This method works as it should in Chrome and Firefox.

I have also tried to update window's dimensions in callback of browser.window.create method, but still the same:

```
browser.windows.create({url:"preview.html",left:left,top:top,type:"popup",width:800,height:1000},function(window){
        browser.windows.update(window.id,{left:left,top:top,width:800,height:1000});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As it states in [Supported APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/api-support/supported-apis/), specifying position is not supported for `windows.update`. I guess it doesn't support for `windows.create` either, or for specifying size.

You may want to raise a bug on [Issue Tracker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/).

Comment: Did that already here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9600565/